# How to echo something in a php while statement when an array returns 0 rows?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, oracle-call-interface

Does anybody know how to echo "Record Not Found " in PHP if an array returns 0 rows in a while loop statement since as I know only when it returns rows, the while loop will keep going and echo something. I very much appreciate it!

```
<?php


while(($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false) 
{  


?>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=&#39;#C0C0C0&#39;;this.style.cursor=&#39;pointer&#39;;" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=&#39;#FFFFFF&#39;;">

<td><div align="center"><a href="http://sv07gisdev1/query/sr.php?CusID=<?=$objResult["FIELDBOOK"];?>"><font size="2.95"><b><?=$objResult["FIELDBOOK"];?></b></font></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["PROJECT"];?></td>  
<td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["DEPT"];?></td>  
<td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["COMMUNITY"];?></div></td>  
<td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["CORTE"];?></div></td> 
<td align="center"><?=$objResult["PMB"];?></td>  
<td align="center"><?=$objResult["PME"];?></td> 
<td align="center"><?=$objResult["TYPE"];?></td> 
<td align="center"><?=$objResult["AREA"];?></td> 
<td align="center"><?=$objResult["OFFICESUPERVISOR"];?></td> 
<td align="center"><?=$objResult["STATUS"];?></td> 
<td align="center"><A HREF=http://10.56.12.59/surveys/notes/<?=$objResult["YEAR"];?>/<?=$objResult["FIELDBOOK"];?>><font size="2.8">View Folder</font></A></td> 
</tr>

<?php
} 

?>  

</table>  

<?php  
oci_close($objConnect);  
}  
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

Don't echo it inside the while loop.

If the query doesn't return any rows, the code in the while loop will never be executed.

Either

1. Do it before the while loop by checking number of rows returned (Sorry, I don't really know how to check that with OCI. A comment on your question suggested using `oci_num_rows`, but the documentation says that function does not return the number of rows selected.) Anyway, it would be something like this:

   ```
   if (however you check for rows in oci_) {
       while(($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
           $gotSomeRows = true;
           // output the rows
       }
   } else {
       echo "Record not found";
   }
   ```
2. Do it after the loop by checking that a variable you set inside the loop exists.

   ```
   while(($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
       $gotSomeRows = true;
       // output the rows
   }
   if (!isset($gotSomeRows)) {
       echo "Record not found";
   }
   ```